# Mongoose Schema Inheritance : entity.entitySchema.extend is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have defined a base Schema as follows, and using [`mongoose-schema-extend`](https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend)

**`testEntitySchema.js`**

```
var entitySchema = {
    entityId: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    type: {
        type: String
    },
    subcategory: {
        type: String
    }
};
module.exports.entitySchema = entitySchema
```

I am trying to extend the above schema and creating a model as follows,

```
module.exports = function (Service) {
    var extend = require('mongoose-schema-extend');
    entity = require('./testEntitySchema');
    var model = null;
    var modelName = '_entity';
    console.log("entity schema is" + entity);
    try {
        model = Service.getModel(modelName);
    } catch (error) {
        var musicEntitySchema = entity.entitySchema.extend({
            category: String
        });
        model = Service.createModel('_entity', musicEntitySchema, {
            name: 'text'
        }, '_entity');
    }

    return model;
};
```

and Service.js looks as follows,

```
'use strict';
(function () {
    let dbHelper = require('./DbHelper');
    module.exports = {
        createModel: function (modelName, entityDef, indexObject, collection) {
            return dbHelper.createModel(modelName, entityDef, indexObject, collection);
        }
```

**dbHelper.js**

```
createModel: function (modelName, schemaObject, indexObject, collection) {
            var modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema(schemaObject);
            if (indexObject) {
                modelSchema.index(indexObject);
            }
            return collection ? mongoose.model(modelName, modelSchema, collection) : mongoose.model(modelName, modelSchema);
        }
```

But the above way of extending gives an error as  **entity.entitySchema.extend is not a function**

Comment: You cannot use extend without using `Schema` in testEntitySchema.js ( `var entitySchema = new Schema({...` , which you are doing later in DbHelper). Resolving this, I ran into multiple other errors with your code. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve with this complicated structure?

Comment: @TalhaAwan how should i modify the above?

Comment: @TalhaAwan any idea bro

Comment: I can post an answer with working example by keeping a simple structure if you like. Or would you like to the current structure? Because I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with it,

Comment: @TalhaAwan please post a sample. what is your contact email?

Comment: are you there ?

Comment: Sharing code in a few minutes.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5XLwA8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139678/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-talha-awan).

Comment: i tried your sample, it says TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `paths`","Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.","at

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168623/cannot-create-mongo-model-using-discriminator-mongoose